# mongodb join on array elements

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 1 collection **user** which looks as follows

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId("70c7ad56ea3ef6002f76df7b"),
  username: "Joe",
  following: [ ObjectId("50c7ad56ea3ef6002f76df7b"), ObjectId("40c7ad56ea3ef6002f76df7b") ]
}
```

the following object contains _ids of other users from the **user** collection. I would like to have a query which gives me the username of each of the users in the following array for any selected user and get the followin results

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId("70c7ad56ea3ef6002f76df7b"),
  username: "Joe",
  following: [ 
   { ObjectId("50c7ad56ea3ef6002f76df7b"), username: "Bill" }, 
   { ObjectId("40c7ad56ea3ef6002f76df7b"), username: "Ann"} 
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `lookup` and then map result to create your final result

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "user",
      "localField": "following",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "following"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      following: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$following",
          "as": "z",
          "in": {
            _id: "$$z._id",
            username: "$$z.username"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

example :https://mongoplayground.net/p/pLgvZenAG84
you could add `$match` to find specific user